# como saber la direción IP con c

Tags: c, ip

Quería saber si hay alguna función en c para saber la IP. He hecho esta función pero preferiría no usar `system`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

void obtener_id(char[]);
void limpiar(char[]);

int main()
{
    char ID[13];
    obtener_id(ID);
    printf("La Id de tu ordenador es: %s",ID);
    return 0;
}



void obtener_id(char lectura[])
{

    FILE *f;
    char auxiliar[62];
    char *puntero;
    int i;
    f=fopen("archivo.txt","wt");
    fclose(f);
    Sleep(500);
    system("ipconfig > archivo.txt"); //guarda la respuesta del cmd en un archivo .txt

    Sleep(500); //le doy tiempo al cmd para que escriba todo lo que tiene que escribir antes de abrirlo para lecura.

    f=fopen("archivo.txt","rt");

    for(i=0;i<13;i++)
    {
        fgets(auxiliar,62,f);
    }

    fgets(auxiliar,62,f);
    limpiar(auxiliar);
    puntero=strtok(auxiliar,":");
    puntero=strtok(NULL,": ");
    strcpy(lectura,puntero);

}

void limpiar(char frase[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(frase);i++)
    {
        if(frase[i]=='\n')
        {
            frase[i]='\0';
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ya respondieron a tu pregunta en el siguiente enlace [Get IP address of an interface on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283494/get-ip-address-of-an-interface-on-linux) o también en este [Get my IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800319/how-do-i-get-my-ip-address-in-c-on-linux)

Comment: Me acaba de surgir una pregunta con base en lo que comentas. Porque sí, es cierto que los dos enlaces anteriores responden a la pregunta de nuestro compañero, sin embargo, están en otro idioma, entonces no creo que se pueda marcar esta pregunta como duplicada o proporcionar esos enlaces sea una respuesta 100% válida, ya que no están respondiendo en el idioma oficial de nuestra comunidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int
main()
{
 int fd;
 struct ifreq ifr;

 fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

 /* Esta configuracion sirve para obtener la IPV4 */
 ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

 /* Esto sirve para apuntar al "eth0" (osea el puerto ethernet por así decirlo)*/
 strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ-1);

 ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);

 close(fd);

 /* resultado de tu IP */
 printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr));

 return 0;
}
```

También te tengo que mencionar que esto es para sistemas linux. Por ultimo, si no te funciona el **eth0**, utiliza **wlan0**

Comment: Mucho mejor así